# Vue.js list rendering just when IDE updates

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, quasar-framework

I created a page to show all events that I created, the problem is that when entering the page, no event is shown, only the add events button. And as soon as I hit enter in the IDE and add an empty line anywhere in the code, the list magically appears. Can anyone explain to me the reason for this?

[image: This is my home page, where the listed events should appear.]

[image: As soon as I hit ENTER on any line in the VSCode, the list magically appears.]

I'm using Quasar and Firebase, I'll let my HTML and Javascript code here if anyone has any idea why this is happening

**HTML**

```
<template>
  <q-page class="flex flex-center bg-primary column">
    <q-btn
      to="/adicionar-evento"
      color="grey-9"
      padding="16px 50px"
      class="q-mt-lg"
    >
      <q-icon left size="2.5em" name="add_circle" />
      Adicionar um novo evento
    </q-btn>
    <div v-for="evento in eventos" :key="evento.id" class="partidaDiv row">
      <div class="column colunaPartida">
        <h1 class="dataHorario">{{ evento.data.slice(0, 5) }}</h1>
        <h1 class="dataHorario">{{ evento.horaInicio }}</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="column colunaPartida2">
        <h1 class="dataHorario">{{ evento.quadra.label }}</h1>
        <h1 class="textoLocal">{{ evento.quadra.value }}</h1>
        <h1 class="textoLocal">Cachoeirinha, Rio Grande do Sul</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="column colunaPartida3">
        <q-icon name="person" color="white" size="2rem" />
        <h1 class="dataHorario">
          {{ evento.numeroVagasPreenchidas }}/{{ evento.numeroVagasJogadores }}
        </h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <q-item>
      <h1></h1>
    </q-item>
  </q-page>
</template>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
import db from "src/boot/firebase";
import {
  collection,
  getDocs,
  orderBy,
  query,
  addDoc,
  onSnapshot,
  deleteDoc,
  doc,
  getDoc,
  updateDoc,
} from "firebase/firestore";

export default {
  setup() {
    return {
      name: "IndexPage",
      eventos: [],
    };
  },
  async mounted() {
    const ordersRef = collection(db, "eventos");
    const q = query(ordersRef, orderBy("data"));

    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
      snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
        let eventoChange = change.doc.data();
        eventoChange.id = change.doc.id;
        if (change.type === "added") {
          this.eventos.unshift(eventoChange);
        }
      });
    });
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have any error in the console/network requests that are not fully completed maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out, I was using `setup()` instead of `data()`.